# How to sort posts by date (FLASK, PYTHON, SQLALCHEMY)

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I would like to know how sort the posts displayed on the home page by data uploaded, I have dates saved to each post in the database. At the moment they are displayed in alphabetical order.

this is the route for the page I would like to display the images

HOME ROUTE:

```
@views.route("/")
def home():
    title = Post.query.get("title")
    date = Post.query.get("date")
    images = os.listdir(os.path.join(staticpath, "uploads"))
    return render_template('home.html', images=images, user=current_user, title=title, date=date, Post=Post, User=User)
```

HTML for page I want to display images by date

HTML PAGE:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}



<section class="list">
  {% for image in images %}
    <p> title: {{ Post.query.filter_by(name=image).first().title }}</p>
    <p> date: {{ Post.query.filter_by(name=image).first().date}}</p>
    <p> OP ID: {{ Post.query.filter_by(name=image).first().user_id}}
    <section class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + image) }}"width = 530>

    </section>



    <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + image) }}" style="absolute: 600;" download>{{ image }}</a>


    <p class="solid" style="border-style: solid;"></p>
  {% endfor %}
</section>


{% endblock %}
```

this is the database that posts are stored, it includes date

DATABASE MODEL:

```
class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = db.Column(db.String(100))
    date = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default = func.now())
    minetype = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("user.id"))
```

Comment: You would usually do something like `posts = Post.query.order_by(Post.date)`

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would change the handler and the template as per below, which will allow you to achieve:

- all `Post`s will be loaded in one query, and immediately sorted
- you will not be making DB queries within the template, making cleaner separation of concerns

```
def home():
    title = Post.query.get("title")
    date = Post.query.get("date")
    # images below are list of strings
    images = os.listdir(os.path.join(staticpath, "uploads"))
    # images below is a collection of `Post` instances (and it is sorted)
    images = Post.query.filter(Post.name.in_(images)).order_by(Post.date)
    return render_template('home.html', images=images, user=current_user, title=title, date=date, Post=Post, User=User)
```

and your template would change as below:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block title %}home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<section class="list">
  {% for image in images %}
    <p> title: {{ image.title }}</p>
    <p> date: {{ image.date }}</p>
    <p> OP ID: {{ image.user_id }}</p>
    <section class="col-md-3 col-sm-6" >
      <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + image.name) }}" width = 530>
    </section>

    <a href="{{ url_for('static', filename='uploads/' + image.name) }}" style="absolute: 600;" download>{{ image }}</a>

    <p class="solid" style="border-style: solid;"></p>
  {% endfor %}
</section>

{% endblock %}
```